# xelatex — remove line spacing in verbatim environment

Tags: verbatim, line-spacing

I am using a lot the verbatim environments. Today I notice that there is a really disturbing (and too large) space between lines in verbatim environment :
[image]

How can I remove them ?

EDIT (xelatex):
minimal example (you need a monospaced font with u2592 character support)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra,%
            lmodern,%
            fancyvrb}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{VRB}{Verbatim}{baselinestretch=.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
\end{verbatim}
\begin{VRB}
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
\end{VRB}
\end{document}
\begin{
```

Comment: the standard verbatim environment doesn't do anything about baseline spacing, it's just whatever is already set up for the current font size.

Comment: I'd like to see that myself... it looks disturbing! Can you provide a minimal example that replicates this?

Comment: @Werner My guess is that the ttfamily is perceived differently by the mind than the rmfamily of the font.  An optical illusion, if you will.  I have been known to reduce the tt font size in my own documents for this reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to completely remove the leading, you need to set `\baselineskip` to a very large negative dimension, so between every pair of lines `\lineskip` glue will be inserted; set this to zero and you're done.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,fancyvrb}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{VRB}{Verbatim}{%
  formatcom={\baselineskip=-\maxdimen\lineskip=0pt}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
▒▒▒
▒▒▒
▒▒▒
\end{verbatim}
\begin{VRB}
▒▒▒
▒▒▒
▒▒▒
\end{VRB}
\end{document}
```

Loading `lmodern` after `fontspec` is completely useless; also `xltxtra` is to be avoided, unless you really need its only feature. Load `fontspec` alone.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**REVISED**

u2592 should not need a space change between lines, unless you have previously changed the line spacing, for example with `setspace` as I show in this MWE.  Then, the approach of my original answer should still apply, but the shift may need to be tailored.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\begin{document}
Start
versus
\begin{verbnobox}[\rmfamily\ifnum\value{VerbboxLineNo}>1\relax\vspace{-8pt}\fi]
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
\end{verbnobox}
the end
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ORIGINAL**

Maybe this would suffice:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\begin{document}
Start
\begin{verbatim}
((((((((((((((((((((((
((((((((((((((((((((((
((((((((((((((((((((((
((((((((((((((((((((((
((((((((((((((((((((((
\end{verbatim}
versus
\begin{verbnobox}[\ifnum\value{VerbboxLineNo}>1\relax\vspace{-3pt}\fi]
((((((((((((((((((((((
((((((((((((((((((((((
((((((((((((((((((((((
((((((((((((((((((((((
((((((((((((((((((((((
\end{verbnobox}
the end
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I missed to specify in the minimal example that I am working with xelatex (even if it is written in the title).
Your example, with xelatex, produce... nothing, I have a blank page...

Comment: --------- EDIT ---------

I replaced the rmfamily by ttfamily and it seems to work. So I try another question : do you think it is possible to do this with the fancyvrb package which allow me to use commands inside a verbatim environment ?

Comment: @krshk I'm sorry that I have no experience with `fancyvrb`, other than superficial exposure.